# Play framework - testing data access layer without started application

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework-2.0

Is there a way to write tests for the data access objects (DAOs) in play framework 2.x without starting an app?

Tests with fake app are relatively slow even if the database is an in-memory H2 as the docs suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the Database object can be constructed directly from the Databases factory, so ended up having a trait like this one:

```
trait DbTests extends BeforeAndAfterAll with SuiteMixin { this: Suite =>
      val dbUrl = sys.env.getOrElse("DATABASE_URL",
            "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testuser=user&password=pass")
     val database = Databases("org.postgresql.Driver", dbUrl, "tests")

     override def afterAll() = {
      database.shutdown()
    }
}
```

then use it the following way:

```
class SampleDaoTest extends DbTests {
   val myDao = new MyDao(database) //construct the dao, database is injected so can be passed
   "read form db" in {
       myDao.read(id = 123) mustEqual MyClass(123)
   } 
}
```

Comment: Can you include a snippet about how you use this in a suite?

Comment: sure, sample added

Answer (score 3):

After experiencing similar issues with execution time of tests using FakeAplication I switched to a different approach. Instead of creating one fake app per test I start a real instance of the application and run all my tests against it. With a large test suite there is a big win in total execution time.

http://yefremov.net/blog/fast-functional-tests-play/

Comment: thanks Dmitry for the answer, interesting approach (innovative for sure :-) ) . I am not a big fan of large integration suites, I prefer to focus on testing each class, and keep only a small set of integration tests for sanity. I am still looking for ways to test only the DAOs with DB without starting a full blown app. But will keep your blog post when implementing the sanity tests.

Answer (score 1):

For unit testing, a good solution is mocking. If you are using Play 2.4 and above, Mockito is already built in, and you do not have to import mockito separately.

For integration testing, you cannot run tests without fake application, since sometimes your DAOs probably require application context information, for example the information defined in application.conf. In this case, you must setup a FakeApplication with fake application configuration so that DAOs have that information.

This sample repo,https://github.com/luongbalinh/play-mongo/tree/master/test, contains tests at service and controller layers, including both unit tests with Mockito and integration tests. Integration tests for DAOs should be very similar to the service tests. Hopefully, it gives you a hint of how to use Mockito to write DAO tests.

Comment: thanks for the answer, we're using mocks to mock the DAOs when testing controllers for example, however we also like to write tests for the DAOs without starting a full app.